# iOS autolayout crash - where do I start?

Tags: ios, autolayout

The following crash occures. Xcode doesn't report any missing constraint (obiously) and the crash doesn't happen every time.
Clearly I have a bug somewhere - but where do I begin investigating?

**Edit**:

So after making an exception breakpoint - I'm seeing the crashing thread that is autolayout code.
A different thread has the following
[image]

Not shockingly this is a resize of a UILabel - what now?

The crash dump:

```
RemoveVariableFromSortedPriorityVectorList(NSISObjectiveLinearExpression *, NSISVariable *)(), /SourceCache/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1047.25/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:136
2014-11-03 00:28:14.899 Cookila copy[3470:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Missing variable UILabel:0x78885670.Width{id: 5777} in variablesSortedByPriorityVectors'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03ba91e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0386a8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03ba9048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x03307b20 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 101
    4   Foundation                          0x03414df4 RemoveVariableFromSortedPriorityVectorList + 386
    5   Foundation                          0x0329af95 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression removeVariable:] + 30
    6   Foundation                          0x034152b9 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:] + 76
    7   Foundation                          0x0329b3f7 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 897
    8   Foundation                          0x0340b5cf -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 421
    9   Foundation                          0x0329a098 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 287
    10  Foundation                          0x0340db9d -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 300
    11  Foundation                          0x03298fc3 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 780
    12  Foundation                          0x03417a77 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 283
    13  Foundation                          0x03294596 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 252
    14  UIKit                               0x029ac30d -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 451
    15  UIKit                               0x029ada4b -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _constraints_didChangeAutoresizingConstraintsArrayForContainedView:] + 233
    16  UIKit                               0x029ad60e -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _setAutoresizingConstraints:] + 240
    17  UIKit                               0x029adea0 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateAutoresizingConstraints] + 117
    18  UIKit                               0x029b77bf -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 110
    19  UIKit                               0x029b7058 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 239
    20  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    21  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    23  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    24  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    25  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    27  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    28  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    29  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    31  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    32  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    33  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    35  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    36  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    37  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    39  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    40  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    41  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    43  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    44  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    45  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    47  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    48  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    49  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    51  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    52  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    53  UIKit                               0x029b7157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    55  UIKit                               0x029b6ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    56  UIKit                               0x029b71d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    57  UIKit                               0x029ab878 __62-[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 43
    58  Foundation                          0x0340e68c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
    59  Foundation                          0x0329e3c5 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    60  UIKit                               0x029ab590 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 225
    61  UIKit                               0x029b7836 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtWindowLevelIfNeeded] + 85
    62  UIKit                               0x0237b324 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 62
    63  UIKit                               0x02388964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    64  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0387c82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    65  QuartzCore                          0x021f045a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    66  QuartzCore                          0x021e4244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    67  QuartzCore                          0x021e40b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    68  QuartzCore                          0x0214a7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    69  QuartzCore                          0x0214bb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    70  QuartzCore                          0x0214c258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    71  CoreFoundation                      0x03b7136e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    72  CoreFoundation                      0x03b712bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    73  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4f254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    74  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4e9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    75  CoreFoundation                      0x03b4e7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    76  GraphicsServices                    0x045815ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    77  GraphicsServices                    0x0458142b GSEventRun + 104
    78  UIKit                               0x02319f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    79  Cookila copy                        0x000e594d main + 141
    80  libdyld.dylib                       0x0415b701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and tell us what the code is that's crashing.

Comment: And can you add a print of the left side panel? So we can see the functions paths?

Comment: It looks like the _real_ issue here is the recursion. My guess is that you have some sort of circularity: constraint A depends on constraint B which depends on constraint A... But that's just a guess.

Comment: I removed a sizetofit I used to have there... Still this happens (once every 10 runs, grr....) - do I have an option to understand which is the control/constraint that is causing a problem? (assume I have "breakpoint on exception" and I have the entire stack thread)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is a resize of a `UILabel` you have constraints on I would try removing the constraints it has, resize it and then set up new constraints (even though they are the same as the previous ones). You can edit/override that method to recibe the label remove and re add constraints.

Code:

```
[label autoRemoveConstraintsAffectingView];
//Resize
//Add constraints
[self.view needsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I removed a sizetofit I used to have there... Still this happens (once every 10 runs, grr....) - do I have an option to understand which is the control/constraint that is causing a problem? (assume I have "breakpoint on exception" and I have the entire stack thread)

Comment: Usually xCode logs whenever you set a constraint that can't be accomplished or a missing key constraint. I recommend you take a look at https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout its much more efficient when dealing with constraints problems, shorter to write code and much more intuitive than Apple's default. It even has methods for crashes that text you exactly what the problem is.